# Getting alias columns in query using REGEX

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have searched high and low and am really struggling to find the appropriate REGEX that would help me retrieve what I want. Assume I have the following query string:

```
SELECT col, col2 AS c2, col3, col * col2 calc FROM...
```

I want a REGEX that will pull out everything between commas where there is a space or an "AS" that proceeds a column alias. It should also exclude the SELECT and FROM. With the example above, I would want the following matches:

```
col2 AS c2
col * col2 calc
```

Essentially, this should remove col and col3 because they don't have aliases. I have tried variations of the following but have been unsuccessful (Note: $colname contains the alias):

```
/(SELECT|,)([^,]*{$colname}[^,]*)(FROM|,)/
```

Currently this only returns:

```
, col2 AS c2,
col2 AS c2
, col2 AS c2,
col2 AS c2
```

I feel I am close but I need some guidance. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [`(?:\G(?!\A),|SELECT)(?:\s+\S+,)*\s*\K\S+\s*(?:\*|AS)\s*(?:(?!FROM)[^,])*(?!\w)`](https://regex101.com/r/YWAZRC/1) will work.

Comment: Thank you for your time. That removed all the , col2 AS c2 but didn't get me col * col2 calc.

Comment: How did you use it? See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/hWxiFV).

Comment: Regex are the wrong tool to parse anything. Use a SQL parser, this'll be much easier and more reliable. Google finds e.g. https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser

Comment: `preg_match` only returns the first match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Awesome! That works. I had preg_match instead of preg_match_all. Put your response as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: What if `col * col2` be `col + col2`?

Comment: @revo I just changed this (?:\*|AS) to (?:\+|\-|\/|\*|\%|AS)

Comment: @Dustin, use `[\p{S}\p{P}]` to match any punctuation/symbol. Or `[[:punct:]]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, that is much better.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew One last question, how can I tell it to ignore all commas between parenthesis? For example, ignore everything in the concat command: SELECT name, Concat(street, ' ', city, ', ', state, ' ', zipcode) AS address

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/YWAZRC/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is next to impossible to handle SQL string parsing with one regex, you should look for a more generic solution like [PHP-SQL-Parser](https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser).

The regex I have come up with is an ad-hoc work around that can be further precised, adjusted, etc. to fit the needs of a specific project:

```
(?:\G(?!\A),|SELECT)(?:\s+[^\s,]+(?:\([^()]*\))?,)*\s*\K[^\s,]+\s*(?:(?![()',])[[:punct:]]|AS)\s*(?:(?!FROM)[^,])*(?!\w)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YWAZRC/4).

Here is what it does:

- `(?:\G(?!\A),|SELECT)` - the end of the previous successful match and a comma after (`\G(?!\A),`) or (`|`) a literal `SELECT` substring
- `(?:\s+[^\s,]+(?:\([^()]*\))?,)*` - zero or more sequences (`(?:...)*`) of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `[^\s,]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and a comma
  - `(?:\([^()]*\))?` - an optional substring like `(...)` (a `(`, then 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, and then a `)`)
  - `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding the text matched so far (so, `SELECT abc, Contains(...),` will get omitted from the match, but will be required for the match)
- `[^\s,]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `,`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(?:(?![()',])[[:punct:]]|AS)` - either

  - `(?![()',])[[:punct:]]` - any punctuation or symbol char but a `(`, `)`, `'` and `,`
  - `|` - or
  - `AS` - a literal `AS` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:(?!FROM)[^,])*` - zero or more chars other than a comma not starting a `FROM` char sequence (it is a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat))
- `(?!\w)` - not followed with a word char.